# Display a custom warning in Xcode when using a deprecated method

Tags: xcode, llvm

Refactoring old code, I want to change the following method:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
     // original logic
}
```

to:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame andDelegate:(id<myDelegateProtocol>)delegate
{
     // original logic

    if(delegate)
    { 
        _delegate = delegate; 
    }
}
```

To ensure that no dependent code breaks, I update the original method to reference the old method, like so:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
     return [self initWithFrame:frame andDelegate:nil];
}
```

However, if anyone is still consuming that original method, I want Xcode to fire a warning (similar to when methods in iOS get deprecated). Ideally, something like:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame __warning__(@"This method has been replaced to ensure that you set the delegate. Please update your code.");
{
     return [self initWithFrame:frame andDelegate:nil];
}
```

Note that these deprecations may happen before a new version iOS is released.

Comment: declaring     - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame__attribute__((deprecated("Use initWithFrame: andDelegate"))); in the interface doesn't work??

Comment: Well. Yes it does. Thanks! Make it an answer and I'll accept. Thanks!

Comment: I thought you tried that already! However posted as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the interface file, do this:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame__attribute__((deprecated("Use initWithFrame: andDelegate")));
```

Answer (score 2):

For completeness, I'l also add that if you want to stop someone using a particular method, you can use the "unavailable" flag, e.g.

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame__attribute__((unavailable("Use initWithFrame: andDelegate")));
```

This fires an error, rather than a warning.

You can find more information at [clang.llvm.org](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#messages-on-deprecated-and-unavailable-attributes)